# Optimize readin binary file data to buffer in C++

Tags: c++, file, optimization, binary, c++17

i wrote a small commandline tool i need to loop and iterate a huge fileserver.
The logic is really simple. But it needs to much time. And i found the problem
is to read binary files into a buffer. I want to hold the implementation easy
because its c++ and some others have to understand the code too.

```
std::ifstream input( foundFile.c_str(), std::ios::binary );
std::vector<unsigned char> buffer(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(input), {});
```

At the end i guess i have to refactor to chunk reading. But in general why
is it so slow about this way to readin a file binary?

complete source:
https://gitlab.com/Onnebrink/cltools/-/blob/main/src/dupfind/dupfind.cpp

Comment: It is slow because it reads and inserts each character individually. Do you really need `std::vector<unsigned char>` instead of `std::string`?

Comment: Fundamentally, single char reading is slow because you have to do a system call per byte in the file - unless you go through a library that does buffering, but then it has to ensure that the buffer is invalidated if something changes the file behind your back, which may again require a system call per read from the buffer, so...  On the other hand, a bulk read can grab several megabytes (or more) per system call.

Comment: Thanks, ok, so I will optimize this to read it in blocks/chunks of 1024 or 4096 chars. And second loop to calc hash i can prevent too this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, its much faster. I guess i have to play a little bit with bufferSize.
Perhaps 4096byte is to little. But I dont have an good overview about the average cases of the fileSizes it will be found. Perhaps i should make it more adaptive depending on founded filesize

```
  unsigned long long calcHash(string &foundFile) {
  const int bufferSize=4096;
  unsigned long long hashValue = 0xeba29ce484222325ULL;
  unsigned long long magicPrime = 0xad3760fd485d7f11ULL;
  ifstream inFile(foundFile.c_str(), std::ios::binary);
  vector<char> buffer(bufferSize);
  while (!inFile.eof()) {
    inFile.read(buffer.data(), bufferSize);
    for (streamsize i = 0; i < inFile.gcount(); i++)
      hashValue ^= buffer[i], hashValue *= magicPrime;
  }
  return hashValue;
}
```